# Combine a VBS script and mp3/other extensions into an executable

Tags: vbscript, mp3, exe

I`d like to combine a VBS script file with an mp3 file audio

I mean ,I want the script to automatically play an mp3 audio in the background,and running the script simultaneously

Otherwise, I do consider writing the script in another language

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this vbscript can give you an idea how to play a music from an url

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL_Music
URL_Music = "http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
Call Play(URL_Music)
'*************************************************
Sub Play(URL)
Dim Sound
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")               
Sound.URL = URL
Sound.settings.volume = 100                               
Sound.Controls.play                                     
do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0                
    wscript.sleep 100                                       
loop                                                    
wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000 
End Sub
'*************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks for the script ,it really helped me.I guess it doesn`t work offline

Comment: @Fantasy if you want to play with mp3 file stored on your computer, just change the URL variable with yours ! Example : URL_Music = "c:\temp\myfile.mp3"

Answer (score 0):

> I want the script to automatically play an mp3 audio in the
>   background,and running the script simultaneously.

You can give a try for this new vbscript that i made for you, in order to play music in background while the script is running another task until to finish up and the music will stop too.

```
'**********************************Description in English***********************************
'This vbscript is created by Hackoo on 29/09/2019
'Sometimes some tasks can be taken a lot of time to end up.
'This code is created in order to play music in background while the script is running another
'task until to finish up and the music will stop too.
'So, the user can listen to the music playing while the script is running another task.
'**********************************Description en Français**********************************
'Parfois, certaines tâches peuvent prendre beaucoup de temps pour finir.
'Ceci est créé afin de jouer de la musique en arrière-plan pendant que,
'le script exécute une autre tâche jusqu’à la terminer et la musique s’arrêtera aussi.
'Ainsi, l'utilisateur peut écouter la musique pendant que le script exécute une autre tâche.
'*******************************************************************************************
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "The script is already Running" & vbCrlf &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"The script is already Running"    
    WScript.Quit  
Else
    Call Run_as_Admin()
    Dim Title,EndUP,WS,fso,Temp,WSF_File,URL_Music,CMD,Process_Music,StartTime,Duration
    Title = "Playing music while another task is running by "& Chr(169) &" Hackoo 2019"
    EndUP = False
    Set WS = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    WSF_File = Temp & "\Music.wsf"
    URL_Music = Random_Music
    Call Create_WSF_Music_File()
    CMD = "wscript.exe " & DblQuote(WSF_File) & " //job:PlayMusic "& DblQuote(URL_Music) &""
    Set Process_Music = WS.Exec(cmd)

    WS.Popup "Playing this Radio music "& DblQuote(URL_Music) & vbCrlf &_
    "in the background while the script is running another task until to finish it"_
    ,5,Title,vbInformation + vbSystemModal

    Do While Process_Music.Status = 0
        If EndUP = False Then
'**********************************************************************************************************************
'Your Main Code goes Here
StartTime = Timer
Call RUN_CMD ( _
            "echo.>%Tmp%\LogCMD.txt" &_
            "& (Tracert.exe www.codereview.stackexchange.com" &_
            "& Ping www.codereview.stackexchange.com" &_
            "& Tracert.exe www.google.com" &_
            "& Ping www.google.com" &_
            "& NetStat -abnof)>>%Tmp%\LogCMD.txt" &_
            "& Start /MAX %Tmp%\LogCMD.txt"_
            )

            Duration = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0)
            WS.Popup "The task had taken a run time until its completion about :" & vbCrlf &_
            vbTab & convertTime(Duration) & vbCrlf & _
            vbTab & WScript.ScriptName,10,Title,vbExclamation + vbSystemModal
'**********************************************************************************************************************
        Else
            On Error Resume Next  'to ignore "invalid window handle" errors
            Process_Music.Terminate
            On Error Goto 0
            EndUP = True
        End If
    Loop
End If
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_WSF_Music_File()
    Dim oWSF
    Set oWSF = fso.OpenTextFile(WSF_File,2,True)
    oWSF.WriteLine "<job id=""PlayMusic"">"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "<script language=""Vbscript"">"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Dim URL_Music"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "URL_Music = WScript.Arguments(0)"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Call Play(URL_Music)"
    oWSF.WriteLine "Function Play(URL)"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Dim Sound"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Set Sound = CreateObject(""WMPlayer.OCX"")"               
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Sound.URL = URL"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Sound.settings.volume = 100"                               
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Sound.Controls.play"                                     
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0"                
    oWSF.WriteLine      "wscript.sleep 100"                                       
    oWSF.WriteLine  "Loop"  
    oWSF.WriteLine "End Function"
    oWSF.WriteLine  "</script>"
    oWSF.WriteLine "</job>"
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function RUN_CMD(StrCmd)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell") 
    MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
    Result = ws.run(MyCmd,0,True)
    EndUP = True
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Random_Music()
    Dim URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6,ListMusic,i,j,tmp
    URL1 = "http://94.23.221.158:9197/stream"
    URL2 = "http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
    URL3 = "http://vr-live-mp3-128.scdn.arkena.com/virginradio.mp3"
    URL4 = "http://185.52.127.168/fr/30201/mp3_128.mp3?origine=fluxradios"
    URL5 = "http://icecast.skyrock.net/s/natio_mp3_128k"
    URL6 = "http://185.52.127.173/fr/30601/mp3_128.mp3?origine=tunein"
    ListMusic = array(URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6)
    Randomize
    For i = 0 To UBound(ListMusic)
        j = Int((UBound(ListMusic) - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        tmp = ListMusic(i)
        ListMusic(i) = ListMusic(j)
        ListMusic(j) = tmp
    Next  
    Random_Music=tmp
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function AppPrevInstance()
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")  
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)
        End With
    End With
End Function    
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'" 
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function convertTime(seconds)
    Dim ConvSec,ConvHour,ConvMin
   ConvSec = seconds Mod 60
   If Len(ConvSec) = 1 Then
         ConvSec = "0" & ConvSec
   End If
   ConvMin = (seconds Mod 3600) \ 60
   If Len(ConvMin) = 1 Then
         ConvMin = "0" & ConvMin
   End If
   ConvHour =  seconds \ 3600
   If Len(ConvHour) = 1 Then
         ConvHour = "0" & ConvHour
   End If
   convertTime = ConvHour & ":" & ConvMin & ":" & ConvSec
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Run_as_Admin()
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
   CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute DblQuote(WScript.FullName) _
   , DblQuote(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```